# jms payment corebundle integtation issue URL return

Tags: symfony, paypal, jmspaymentpaypalbundle

I'm integration the jms payment bundle in symfony 2.6.
I had followed all document in : http://jmspaymentcorebundle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/accepting_payments.html

I'm getting this error :

```
 You must configure a return url.
```

I had configured the return URL into ON in my account , and it seems not working, getting the same error. 
My confirmation url is a page in which there is some text like :

```
  Thank you for your payment. Your transaction has been completed,
  and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you.
  You may log into your account at www.paypal.com to view details of this transaction.
```

The error persists. 
What should i do ?

Comment: Where does that error come from? Which file? Can you show the specific code please?

Comment: Here it is the file : in vendor/jms/payment-paypal-bundle/JMS/Payment/PaypalBundle/Plugin/ExpressCheckoutPlugin.php at line 327

Line 327 : throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure a return url.');

Comment: No that's not where it is! Can you use the debug URL? So for example, if your URL was `http://localhost/submitpayment`, then you append `app_dev.php` to the URL, which would be `http://localhost/app_dev.php/submitpayment`. Then you should be able to see which one of `your` files has the problem. Probably in one of your controller files...

Comment: Already i'm using the frontal controller app_dev.php, in the stack trace when i click on my link to access payment, i'm getting the file which i had told you .
Else, the status is 500 Internal server error, in the controller Orders, in the route " app_orders_paymentcreate " the createpayment action

Comment: The link that you show, only has a partially complete `OrdersController.php` file. Each function needs to return something even if you return null that should be enough. The example function `paymentCreateAction` doesn't actually return anything (except within the if statement), so you'll need to add a return.

Comment: actually no, it already returns : if the Result success, it will redirect to the app_orders_paymentcomplete else , it will redirect to $action->getUrl()

Comment: I had changed the throw $result->getPluginException(); to a redirect to a specific url , and the same error appears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jms payment corebundle URL return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942946/jms-payment-corebundle-url-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , they mean in the controller. I added :

```
'predefined_data' => array(
        'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
            'return_url' => $this->generateUrl('payment_complete', array(
                'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
            ), true),
```

For more documentation http://jmspaymentpaypalbundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html