# jms payment corebundle URL return

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, jmspaymentpaypalbundle

I'm integrating the jms payment bundle in symfony 2.6. I had followed all document in : http://jmspaymentcorebundle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/accepting_payments.html

I'm getting this error :

```
You must configure a return url.
```

I had configured the return URL into ON in my account , and it seems not working, getting the same error. My confirmation url is a page in which there is some text like :

```
 Thank you for your payment. Your transaction has been completed,
 and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you.
 You may log into your account at www.paypal.com to view details of this transaction.
```

The error comes from **paymentCreateAction** in **OrdersController.php**

The error persists. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , they mean in the controller.
I added :

```
    'predefined_data' => array(
            'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
                'return_url' => $this->generateUrl('payment_complete', array(
                    'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
                ), true),
```

For more documentation http://jmspaymentpaypalbundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can solved adding return url and cancel url in your config.yml

```
jms_payment_paypal:
    username: api username
    password: api password
    signature: api signature
    return_url: https://yourdomain.com
    cancel_url: https://yourdomain.com
    debug: true
```